# How does the ARM yield instruction inform other threads that they could start, and how does it compare to WFE?

Tags: arm, armv8

While studying WFE, I came across the YIELD instruction in the [ARMv8 DB](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/db/DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf) manual Section B1.3.3 "The YIELD instruction".

That section says:

> The YIELD instruction provides a hint that the task performed by a thread is of low importance so that it could yield, see YIELD on page C6-1253.

but I'm a bit confused, since I thought that to get another thread prioritized, I would need to inform the Linux kernel to tell the scheduler to prioritize another thread.

So how is YIELD talking to the kernel if at all? I was expecting that a system call like `sched_yield` would be the way to go about it.

Also how does it compare to WFE? WFE says that it can enter a low power usage mode, wouldn't that make more sense if we want to yield?

F1.8.1 "The Yield instruction" also says that an implementation could for example:

> A similar use might be in modifying the arbitration priority of the snoop bus in a multiprocessor (MP) system.

so maybe YIELD is like WFE, and hints at such micro architectural optimizations, but without the possibility of putting the CPU in a low power state which would require an SEV to wake it up latter.

Comment: I'll be honest in that this was something that made me curious as well.  I get WFE/WFI type commands and how they help with spinlock and power, but the yield part was less clear.

Answer (score 2):

Thread in this context refers to a hardware thread for SMT.  You may be more familiar with Intel's branded term "Hyperthreading" for this technology.  With this technology one core may execute multiple hardware threads at the same time.

This is related to but not the same as an operating system thread.  The scheduler is responsible for mapping OS threads to hardware threads.

For more details see this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)

Comment: Are there any ARM cores with SMT?  I think most mainstream ARM cores are just 1 logical core per physical core, so `yield` is presumably just a no-op unless there's other stuff that is useful for it to do as a spin-loop hint.